# How does Instagram use django?

Tags: django, instagram

I don't know if this is the right kind of question to ask here or not. I read that Instagram uses django which is a python web framework. But Instagram is an iOS application. Aren't iOS apps written in objective c? What do they mean by Instagram uses django?

Comment: Yeah you're right - its not the right kind of question to ask here.

Comment: Well, it did get answered well.

Comment: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of

Answer (score 29, accepted):

IOS is the "Frontend" of the application. Django is a backend "Server Side" Web Framework.

For example, if there is an iPhone application that shows you all the latest tutorial videos about baking (lets say you had a website bakingtutorials.com), you would make an iPhone application in objective-c to run as the frontend. In your objective-c iPhone code, you would communicate with a "server" which runs Django/Python. The Server Side (Django) holds the video and other baking data in a database. The Frontend iOS application requests data from the Django application. Client Side & Server Side communication. This is usually accomplished with a RESTful API - which in basic terms, means the iPhone application uses human-readable URLs to grab data from Django/the server's database. This data is sent to the frontend from the server where it is parsed by objective-c and formatted for the application

Answer (score 4):

Instagram uses it for its website and MAYBE for the API. But there's no official information about that.

And yes, you're right: iOS apps are done in objectiveC

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps can either be natively written in objective-c, or they can be webapps, displaying a mobile service hosted on a site, in a WebKit view.

Regardless of what format Instagram uses for their iOS app, django can still be a solution. As a native app, they can still be communicating from the mobile device to the django web server over a REST api interface.

Django does not have to be used exclusively to serve HTML. It can serve any kind of HTTP response you want. This is very common for sites when they have a desktop browser interface, and then also expose some API urls to the same backend, allowing mobile apps to make the same requests.